# Getting all the HTML code from a website that is using React

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the [Thingiverse website](https://www.thingiverse.com/), more specifically the page displaying a "thing", like [this one](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4796603/files) for example. The problem is that when making a get request (using the python urllib or requests package) the response is an empty HTML file containing a lot of header data, some scripts and an empty react-app div:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<head>
    <title>PCB Feet/Standoffs for M3 by scruss - Thingiverse</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="EN">
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
    <meta name="keywords"
        content="things, digital design, physical objects, rapid prototyping, 3D objects, 3D printing, reprap, fabrication, laser cutter, laser, thingaverse, thingyverse">
    <meta name="abstract" content="Share your digital designs for physical objects.">
    <meta name="author" content="Thingiverse.com">
    <meta name="distribution" content="Global">
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="1 days">
    <meta name="robots" content="follow,index">
    <meta name="description"
        content="Download files and build them with your 3D printer, laser cutter, or CNC. Thingiverse is a universe of things.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#248bfb">

    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="PCB Feet/Standoffs for M3 by scruss">
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="Basic &quot;I don&#039;t want my protoboard shorting or gouging holes in my desk&quot; feet/standoffs for M3-drilled 1.6 mm thick PCBs.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/assets/d5/9e/0e/1c/f3/featured_preview_pcb_feet.png">
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta property="twitter:site" content="@thingiverse">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4796603">
    <meta property="twitter:creator" content="@scruss">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152"
        href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/favicon-192x192.png"
        sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/favicon-160x160.png"
        sizes="160x160">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/favicon-96x96.png"
        sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png"
        sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png"
        sizes="32x32">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/img/favicons/mstile-144x144.png">

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Thingiverse - PCB Feet/Standoffs for M3 Comments"
        href="https://rss.thingiverse.com/thing:4796603">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.datadoghq-browser-agent.com/datadog-logs-us.js"></script>
    <script>
        const ddClientToken = "pub24a00142f6aa558abe1827e911e11e58";
            const ddEnv = "production";
            const ddVersion = "2.11.0";

            DD_LOGS.init({
                clientToken: ddClientToken,
                forwardErrorsToLogs: true,
                service: "thingiverse-client",
                env: ddEnv,
                version: ddVersion,
                sampleRate: 20
            });

            
            const ddIsTvNext = true;
            const ddBuildTime = "1617625667";

            DD_LOGS.addLoggerGlobalContext("is_thingiverse_next", ddIsTvNext);
            DD_LOGS.addLoggerGlobalContext("build_time", ddBuildTime);
    </script>

    <script>
        var scripts     = ["https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/thingiverse/build/lib-afbc32d766.js","https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/thingiverse/build/header-aa33d7b171.js","https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/thingiverse/build/footer-df22f3acb4.js","https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/thingiverse/build/things-d4ffa805ef.js","https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/thingiverse/build/orders-e1ac5a6395.js","https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/thingiverse/build/gallery-7fc215e644.js"];
            var stylesheets = [];
            var build_time  = 1617625667;
    </script>
</head>


<script src="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/three.min.bundle.js?1617625667"></script>
<div class="react-app" id="react-app"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.thingiverse.com/site/js/app.bundle.js?1617625667"></script>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s){w._uptime_rum={};w._uptime_rum.uuid='AVO7-994EF0DD9662F23C';w._uptime_rum.url='https://rum.uptime.com/rum/record-data';s=document.createElement('script');s.async=1;s.src='https://uptime.com/static/rum/compiled/rum.js';d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);})(window,document);
</script>
```

This unfortunately isn't the HTML you see when inspecting the page in a browser. I'm guessing React inserts its HTML later on, which is why the div is empty. Is there any way of getting around that and receiving the actual HTML code that you can see in the browser?

Comment: You could use a tool called [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to ensure it loads and then scrape it

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049520/5320906) should give you some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a browser to render the javascript and then extract the rendered HTML. Try selenium. It lets you manage a browser through your python code and interact with web page elements.

Install selenium:

`pip install selenium`

Then something like this to extract the HTML

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver') # Downloaad the chrome driver and replace this path
driver.get("your_url")
# Wait for some element to be rendered or just a blind sleep
print(driver.page_source) # This'll give you the full rendered HTML
driver.close()
```